# why each left ideal of this is minimal?

Tags: abstract-algebra

please first read these then answer my question

Let $D$ be a division ring and r, n be two positive integer numbers such that
$0 ≤ r ≤ n$. Then $H_r(D)$ denotes the left ideal of $M_n(D)$ containing all matrices whose
$j$th column is zero, for every $r < j ≤ n$.

> **Theorem A:** Let $D$ be a division ring and $n$ be a positive integer number.
>   Then for every left ideal $I$ of $M_n(D)$, there exist an invertible matrix $P$ and integer $r$,
>   $0 ≤ r ≤ n$, such that $I = PH_r(D)P^{−1}$.

Now from theorem A how I can conclude that each left ideal of $M_2(D)$ is minimal?
I'm totally confused with this

Comment: This doesn't seem true since $\{0\} = H_0(D) \subsetneq H_1(D) \subsetneq H_2(D) \subsetneq \dots \subsetneq H_n(D)$. So where did you find that?

Comment: I found it from a article

Comment: I didn't see that $n=2$...

Answer (score 2):

You want to show that every *nonzero proper* left ideal of $M_2(D)$ is minimal.

It is clear that $\{0\}=H_0(D)\subsetneq H_1(D)\subsetneq H_2(D)=M_2(D)$.

Let $I$ be a proper nonzero left ideal. Then $I=PH_r(D)P^{-1}$ implies $r>0$, so either $r=1$ or $r=2$. But $r=2$ implies the identity matrix belongs to $H_2(D)$ so it also belongs to $I$: a contradiction to $I$ being proper.

Hence $r=1$. Now, if $J$ is another ideal, $J\ne\{0\}$ and $J\subseteq I$, we have $\{0\}\ne P^{-1}JP\subseteq P^{-1}IP=H_1(D)$. Since $H_1(D)$ *is* a minimal left ideal, we can conclude $P^{-1}JP=P^{-1}IP$, so also $J=I$.

Comment: it seems so true. thank you @egreg

Comment: @egreg: How do you know that $H_1(D)$ is minimal?

Comment: @paf Its dimension as $D$-vector space is $2$; but left ideals have dimension $0$, $2$ or $4$, being isomorphic to $H_r(D)$ for some $r$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.